# How to know when a job in screen finishes?

Tags: gnu-screen, job-control

Is it possible to know if a script executed inside a screen session finished or not? The script can be seen by typing `jobs` and I would like to terminate the `screen session` when the script is finished. How can I do so or can I have the screen terminate itself after the script successfully executes? It is not convenient to do it manually since I run 72 screen sessions at once. It would be really nice to somehow check the status of the jobs inside the screen sessions automatically and print them to `stdout` and have the `screen` sessions terminate when the jobs running within are finished.

Comment: Can't you just execute the jobs in the background?

Comment: "I would like to terminate the screen session when the script is finished." `some_script && exit`

Comment: @John1024 Seems plausible can I stuff it into a detached screen?

Comment: @Vesnog Yes.  The `exit` will cause the window that it is in to close.  If that is the only window in the screen session, then the screen session will close.  If, as shown, `&&` is used, the window will remain open for your inspection if the script fails.  If you want it to close regardless of whether the script succeeded or failed, then replace `&&` with `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just chain the commands 1. `your_script` and 2. `kill this screen session`

Let `foo.sh` be your script. The command to kill a screen session is `kill`. You issue commands to a screen session with `screen -X`, making `screen -X kill` the shell/bash command to kill the screen session you are currently in. You would

```
screen -S the_session_for_my_job
```

to create the screen session and then you would

```
/path/to/foo.sh; screen -X kill
```

This will kill the screen session, independent from the number of windows and will do so after foo.sh has finished.

A more complicated way is to watch process ids and issue the kill command when a certain PID disappears.

Let 12345 the PID of the process you want to watch. Then you would

```
while ps a | grep ^12345;do sleep 2; done; screen -X kill
```

The while loop watches the process list for a process with the PID 12345. If such a process exists, it will sleep 2 seconds before checking again. If no process with this PID exists, the while loop terminates. Then the kill command is issued.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer can I use the second statement with the `stuff` command? Actually I send the commands to a detached screen with a `zsh` script.

Comment: Yes, I saw your other post. It should work just as well as any other string you can `stuff`.

Comment: Better to use `grep "^ *12345"` because may miss it due to padding at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

I use email with the following:

```
command | mail-s job_output to@email.com; exit
```

Or if it's already running you can type  (or copy-paste if there is lots of output) commands to execute after completion:

```
echo $STY done | mail -s job_done to@email.com; exit
```

Comment: Thanks this is a nice option too, but how can it send an email to me.